# 32bit pyodbc for 32bit python (3.6) works with microsoft's 64 bit odbc driver. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, odbc, driver, 32bit-64bit, pyodbc

**What I can observe:**

- I am using windows 7 64bit My code (establish an odbc connection with
  a SQL server on the network, simple reading operations only) is
  written in python 3.6.2 32bit
- I pip installed pyodbc, so I assume that was 32bit as well.
- I downloaded and installed the 64bit "Microsoft® ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server®" from microsoft website.
- My python code connects to
  other computers on the network, which run server2003 32bit and either SQL Server 2005(32bit) or sql2008(32bit).

The setup works.

Moreover: cursory test shows that, the above setup can successfully connect to a computer with Microsoft server2008(64bit) running sql2012(64bit) with the configuration under "SQL Server Network Connection (32bit)" being empty (meaing, the 32bit dll is missing), while the default 64 bit network connection configuration contains the usual config options like ip adress and listening port info.

**My own explanation:** 
[1] the client and the server's OS and ODBC interfaces can be of any 32/64 bit combination, but the protocol that travels thru the network between my computer and the sql computer will be identical.
[2] 32 bit python+pyodbc can talk to microsoft's 64bit odbc driver, because... 32 bit python knows how to use a 64 bit DLL...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 32bit application can NOT invoke a 64bit dll, so python 32bit can not talk to a 64bit driver for sure.

msodbc driver for sql server is in essence a dll file: msodbcsql13.dll

I just found out (which is not even mentioned by microsoft) that "odbc for sql server 13.1 x64" will install a 64bit msodbcsql13.dll in system32 and a 32bit msodbcsql13.dll in SysWOW64 ( 32bit version of "system32" on a 64bit windows system)

I can not however be certain that the network protocol between a 32bit client talking to 64bit sql server will be the same as a 64bit client talking to a 64bit sql server. But, I believe that, once a request is put on the network by the client to the server, 32bit or 64bit doesn't matter anymore. Someone please comment on this

Comment: *"I believe that, once a request is put on the network by the client to the server, 32bit or 64bit doesn't matter anymore."* - That is correct.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you, Is that because, the ODBC specification locks down the protocol to exchange information between the drivers. So that we don't have problems like 32bit/64bit pointer confusions, or problems like an int can be 32 or 64bit. A 64bit odbc driver on a server can understand odbc language spoke by a 32bit odbc client. It is almost like COM object, iron clad specification, regardless of bits.